# What does a domain registrar do?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, dns-zone, domain-registrar, tld

What does a domain registrar actually do? As in, do they facilitate you registering your domain name with the registry? Do they host your domain?

I downloaded a couple of top-level-domain zones, they're just a list of NS records.

So my question is, when I change my domains name servers, am I changing the NS record within the top-level-domain zone file? Or do the top-level-domain zone file point to my registrar, and changing my name servers will update them with my registrar and not the actually TLD zone file?

Any clarification on how the whole thing works would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A domain registrar facilitates registering your domain with the registry.  Some registrars also host your domain, as an optional add-on service - but not all even offer that service.

When you change your Name Servers, your registrar passes on that request to the registry using a protocol called EPP, and the NS is changed within the TLD zone file that is maintained by the registry.